# Ask for VBA Function

Tags: vba

If my input is 900101141234, then I want to change the number to the string "********1234" as the output using VBA Function. My function should also return the number 0 if n is not a 12 digit number.

```
Function Hide_IC(n As String)
Dim n As String

Hide_IC = n
If CStr(IC) <> 12 Then
Range("A2") = 0
Else
Range("A2") = Format(n, "********")
End Function
```

How should I continue?? I have no idea in converting the digit into *

Comment: What are you trying to do in `If CStr(IC) <> 12 Then`? Seems like you wanted to use `Len`.

Comment: @BigBen I want to return the number 0 if n is not a 12 digit number

Comment: There's so much wrong with the code that it doesn't make much sense. You already have an argument named `n` but you're declaring a local variable with the same name. `CStr` converts a number to a string; you should use `Len` instead as BigBen said. Where does `IC` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with the code that you provided.

Firstly, as a function, it should normally return a value of some sort. You would usually use a Sub to just perform some actions.

Next, you are declaring `n As String` within the procedure when it has already been declared as an argument for the function.

Rewriting the function:

```
Function Hide_IC(n As String) As String
    If Len(n) <> 12 Then
        Hide_IC = 0
    Else
        Hide_IC = String(8, "*") & Right(n, 4)
    End If
End Function
```

You can then use this function just like an inbuilt Excel worksheet function, so if your data is in cell B11, you can use this in another cell:

```
=Hide_IC(B11)
```

Regards